# Multiple Devices in Windows 10 Settings?

Tags: windows-10, nfc

[image]

As seen in the above image, Windows 10 is showing that multiple NFC devices exist on my computer.

The machine itself only has one NFC device present hardware-wise, but there are the following entries in Device Manager:

- **Proximity Devices** > NFC Proximity Provider (`BCMNFCIC\NFC_PROVIDER`)
- **System NFC Devices** > NFC SMBus Device (`ACPI\VEN_BCM&DEV_2F05`)

What is causing this double entry, how do I resolve it, and what could this be doing to my machine?

Comment: using `i.stack.imgur.com` instead of `prntscr.com` insures your pictures is visible to all visitors.

Comment: @Ramhound I'll take care of that later today, then

Comment: fixed the image.

Answer (score 0):

Those are simply 2 different categories and NFC being NFC supports both.
Take for example a simple Infrared-Sensor (the one on most smartphones)

The sensor is only being used to let the device know when to turn off the screen and is not able to communicate and therefore would go into the Proximity group. NFC however can be used for communication as well as proximity sensor.

Comment: How does the author, prevent the same device, from appearing twice in the list though?  Can you provide details steps to solve their problem?